# Handing a Bounding Box (bbox) to an overpass query

Tags: qgis-modeler, overpass-api, bbox, quickosm

I would like to incorporate the results of overpass-queries into a model, which in the end gives me a clipped union of these results (all roads within a specific area).

The challenge is to automate the query by handing it a bbox based on the area of interest.

Is there a way to do so? Could "Oriented minimum bounding box" help me in this?

Further specification:

[image]

I am using the graphical modeller of QGis to union several different types of roads (motorway, primary, etc) which I downloaded from OSM via the QuickOSM extension for QGis. I am doing several downloads due to possible crashes of QGis when forcing the processing/download of to much data via QuickOSM.

Right now the data has to be downloaded manually, but since I will have to do this several times for different regions I would like to automate the whole process further by including the download into the model.

My question: Is there a way to automatically hand a bbox based on my current area (available as shape) to an overpass API query?

Comment: QuickOSM is available in the Processing toolbox. You need to give your extent in the overpass API call. The overpass API will replace all {{bbox}} in your query.

Comment: That I do know. The question is, if that extent can be adapted automatically to the current area of interest, or if I need to change the extent by hand for each rerun.

Comment: "clipped union of these results (all roads within a specific area)" - is it OK to get roads outside bbox? "all roads within a specific area" imply that some are OK as long as everything inside bbox is obtained, clipped suggests that not.

Comment: I would need everything within the bbox, the clipping with a manually built mask would be the last step along the way. Before that I do not care whether there is data crossing the borders of bbox and/or mask.